# TypeScript generics with Angular2 injector

Tags: angularjs, typescript, code-injection, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to use dependancy injection in angular using an injector. I want to me able to instantiate types at runtime depending on what this component is sent.

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceInjectionManager {
    private _injector: ReflectiveInjector;

    constructor() {
        this._injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            {
                provide: Http,
                useFactory: (backendInstance: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                    return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
                },
                deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
            },
            AppSettings,
            HierarchyService
        ]);
    }


    public resolve<T extends HierarchyService>(type:any): T {

        return this._injector.get(type);
    }

}
```

I can't seem to find a way to pass a type. I have taken multiple approaches including:

```
    public resolve<T extends HierarchyService>(T): T {

        return this._injector.get(T);
    }
```

It seems that generics in TypeScript are not the same as in .NET.